# visual studio 2010 intellisense without creating a project/solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I want to use visual studio intellisense without creating a project( project too big ).

My questing : Is it even possible? If so, how?

To understand better what I want here's some additional info:

The functionality should be similar to ctags in linux. I haven't used ctags much, but at a point in time, when I was coding in vim, I know I had to run ctags to generate the function headers info in the folder which I was working in and then, when I opened a file with vim in a folder which contained ctags generated files, autocompletion worked.

Why I need this:

The project in which I'm working at is very big, and doensn't provide .sln files for Visual Studio 2010, however, when I open a file from the project folder, I want to be able somehow(if it's possible) to use autocompletion. I'm open to using other editors/IDEs too if I'd be able to use autocomplete without creating a project, however I'd prefer using Visual Studio, because debugging is easy cause of the Attach to Process feature.

PS: Languages used: C and C++

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?